# How to wait and get the proper result in caller class from a block function of second class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a difficulty to get the result from a block function from second class.

The below function returns boolean value from `first class`.

```
    - (BOOL)loadAccountWithUsername:(NSString *)username
                       password:(NSString *)password
                       hostname:(NSString *)hostname
                    oauth2Token:(NSString *)oauth2Token
{
    __block _Bool bLoadedSuccess = false;

    self.imapSession = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
    self.imapSession.hostname = hostname;
    self.imapSession.port = 993;
    self.imapSession.username = username;
    self.imapSession.password = password;
    if (oauth2Token != nil) {
        self.imapSession.OAuth2Token = oauth2Token;
        self.imapSession.authType = MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2;
    }
    self.imapSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeTLS;
    MasterViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;
    self.imapSession.connectionLogger = ^(void * connectionID, MCOConnectionLogType type, NSData * data) {
        @synchronized(weakSelf) {
            if (type != MCOConnectionLogTypeSentPrivate) {

            }
        }
    };

    // Reset the inbox
    self.messages = nil;
    self.totalNumberOfInboxMessages = -1;
    self.isLoading = NO;
    self.messagePreviews = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"checking account");
    self.imapCheckOp = [self.imapSession checkAccountOperation];
    [self.imapCheckOp start:^(NSError *error) {
        MasterViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        NSLog(@"finished checking account.");

        if (error == nil) {
            [strongSelf loadLastNMessages:NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_LOAD];
            bLoadedSuccess = true;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error loading account: %@", error);
        }

        strongSelf.imapCheckOp = nil;
    }];

    return bLoadedSuccess;
}
```

I want to call this function from `2nd class` and get the result.

```
masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
BOOL loadsuccess = [masterViewController loadAccountWithUsername:username password:password hostname:hostname oauth2Token:nil];
```

The issue is, I am getting result as `false` in `2nd class loadsuccess`, since the `loadAccountWithUsername` gets the result in block function only after few minutes. By the time, 2nd class gets returned with the `false` value instead of `true`

How can a caller class wait and get the proper result from the block function from another class?

Kindly advise.

Comment: You'd generally change the method prototype to something like `loadAccountWithUsername... completion:` and pass in a completion block that you invoke within the nested block passed to `self.imapCheckOp start` ... you have to ditch the BOOL return type, but you also have to ditch the idea of synchronous execution.

Comment: Use delegate methods.

Comment: Pass first class delegate to the second class, and implement a method in the first class that gets the result as bool. Then when the second class done its work, call this method with this delegate. @FawadMasud's idea.